# ConcurrentLinkedQueue Questions

Tags: java, concurrency

Could you please clarify if we need to use explicit synchronization or locks for using ConcurrentLinkedQueue? I am specifically interested in knowing if sync calls are needed for following ConcurrentLinkedQueue methods.

- add
- clear
- size

Possibly size is the only method which might require explicit sync since it's a not an atomic method but ConcurrentLinkedQueue java docs say that

> "Beware that, unlike in most
>   collections, the size method is NOT a
>   constant-time operation. Because of
>   the asynchronous nature of these
>   queues, determining the current number
>   of elements requires a traversal of
>   the elements. "

which make me believe that though size call may be slow but it doesn't require any explicit sync call.

Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 4):

clear() is not atomic operation (it is implemented in AbstractQueue class), as Javadoc and source says: "This implementation repeatedly invokes poll until it returns null.". poll is atomic, but if you use offer while clear() is ongoing, you will add something in the middle of clearing, and clear() will delete it...

If you will use clear() you should use LinkedBlockingQueue instead of ConcurrentLinkedQueue.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any explicit synchronization or locks. As [the docs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) state, it is a *thread-safe* collection. This mean each of these methods is correctly atomic (though as you point out, `size()` may be slow).

Answer (score 0):

You should not and do not need to use explicit locking on any of those methods.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you do not need to use explicit synchronization because this is a thread safe collection. Any concurrent access is allowed without worry

Answer (score 0):

It is unnecessary to synchronize to preserve the internal structure of the queue. However it may be necessary to linearise other invariants of your structure.

For instance `size()` is fairly meaningless in any shared mutable container. All it can ever tell you is something about what it was the last time you asked, not *what it is now*, unless you stop the world and prevent concurrent modification. It is only useful for indicative monitoring purposes, you should *never* use it in your algorithm.

Similarly, `clear()` doesn't really mean much without some kind of external intervention. Clear what? The things that are in it at the time you call clear? In a concurrent structure answering *that* is a difficult if not impossible question.

So, you are better off using it as a simple thread-safe queue (only offering and polling) and steering clear of the others unless you externally lock.